# How do I override title and meta tags in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

My goal is simple... I created a page in the WordPress root named *download.php*:

```
<?php
    $heading_bs = 'My bla bla heading..';
    require_once('wp-load.php');
    get_header();
    // My code here...
    get_footer();
?>
```

How do I insert $heading_bs in `<title>` and `meta title`?

How can I make a custom description?

- Don’t tell me to create a custom post type or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach would be to make download.php a template, since otherwise it would not get the required WordPress support for get_header() and get_footer().

The `<title>` tag is created in your header.php template file. You can test in header.php for your special template and adjust accordingly:

```
<title><?php echo (get_page_template() == 'download.php') ? $heading_bs : wp_title() ?></title>
```

You could also test for the existence of the special heading variable:

```
<title><?php echo (isset($heading_bs) && $heading_bs) ? $heading_bs : wp_title() ?></title>
```

or if you would rather keep the standard title statement:

```
<?php if (isset($heading_bs) && $heading_bs) : ?>
<title><?php echo $heading_bs ?></title>
<?php else : ?>
<title>...your current title...</title>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: My theme is custom, I think It is ok to add this code in header.php but I think you mistake something, There may be a if statement like this if($heading_bs){you code} else{normal <head> tag of my theme}. Isn't it? or WP alone can handle this?

Comment: There are several possibilities. I updated the answer to give several options.

Comment: I better use 3rd one because I have no intention to make download.php a page template,

Comment: A problem, Currently my theme don't have a head tag (It was built from scratch) and using wordpress default header. So when I am trying to add <head>, there are two head tag in source. So, I have to remove Wordpress head thg first. any Idea?

Comment: You should look at one of the standard WordPress themes, like Twenty Fifteen, and copy the header.php from that. You can then modify it as you need to.

Comment: `isset($heading_bs) && $heading_bs` is more simply written as `!empty($heading_bs)`